# Distance calculation in mongodb aggregate using cosine

Tags: mongodb, face-recognition, cosine-similarity, euclidean-distance

I am saving face embedding as numpy array in mongodb and using this aggrigate to find distance between to array using euclidean algorithm.

Can someone please help to calculate distance using cosine?

Sample json document is shown below and aggregate should return only those documents whose distance is <= 0.68

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "635ff70a16dfa4cd45f02c43"
  },
  "img_path": "1_11",
  "name": "11",
  "embedding": [
    0.04153144732117653,
    -0.0008036745712161064,
    -0.003807373344898224,
    -0.11769875884056091,
    0.03676579147577286,
    0.09997286647558212,
    -0.044136010110378265,
    -0.1692838966846466,
    -0.003151319921016693,
    -0.03791208565235138,
    -0.010753434151411057,
    -0.024590950459241867,
    0.29803258180618286,
    -0.04285677522420883,
    0.20911607146263123,
    0.04455781728029251,
    0.029769904911518097,
    -0.33982840180397034,
    0.010117404162883759,
    -0.4239773750305176,
    -0.005369218066334724,
    0.0714929848909378,
    0.2586987018585205,
    0.007376951165497303,
    -0.03157464414834976,
    0.11055145412683487,
    -0.052830226719379425,
    -0.16745653748512268,
    0.06054156646132469,
    -0.3206060826778412,
    0.054714761674404144,
    -0.10260075330734253,
    0.2717891037464142,
    -0.16717249155044556,
    0.09896406531333923,
    -0.2952454090118408,
    0.010972617194056511,
    0.24918027222156525,
    -0.2690051198005676,
    0.2626166343688965,
    0.2875710725784302,
    0.13260763883590698,
    0.12771351635456085,
    -0.22898457944393158,
    0.18346519768238068,
    -0.06396391987800598,
    -0.09320224076509476,
    0.02307960018515587,
    -0.3165799081325531,
    0.007051767781376839,
    0.06508949398994446,
    -0.15390481054782867,
    0.07253721356391907,
    0.05360442399978638,
    0.02317194454371929,
    0.2602832019329071,
    0.32494112849235535,
    0.10228901356458664,
    -0.026188479736447334,
    0.051889386028051376,
    -0.17360231280326843,
    0.2001030296087265,
    0.11494665592908859,
    -0.1468532681465149,
    -0.3037929832935333,
    0.4243096113204956,
    -0.3967720568180084,
    -0.1580674648284912,
    0.1209937185049057,
    -0.3088080883026123,
    0.14958013594150543,
    -0.1499250829219818,
    0.1793043464422226,
    0.042404696345329285,
    -0.17440882325172424,
    0.014482134953141212,
    0.17418500781059265,
    -0.29781395196914673,
    0.3233387768268585,
    -0.13625966012477875,
    -0.2671341001987457,
    0.1924743503332138,
    -0.0009934399276971817,
    -0.13012878596782684,
    0.04334684833884239,
    -0.047992683947086334,
    -0.0871971845626831,
    0.026077959686517715,
    0.23131468892097473,
    -0.04128192365169525,
    0.11939074844121933,
    0.2669318914413452,
    0.02978256344795227,
    -0.07513333857059479,
    0.09071725606918335,
    0.14345180988311768,
    -0.2577393651008606,
    -0.1343279629945755,
    0.03614958003163338,
    0.04753677546977997,
    0.4799879491329193,
    0.12120816111564636,
    0.04913831502199173,
    -0.1472567766904831,
    -0.1521947830915451,
    -0.016198324039578438,
    0.0709092766046524,
    0.2530268430709839,
    -0.10402888804674149,
    0.12103180587291718,
    -0.00816013291478157,
    -0.15727344155311584,
    -0.09354865550994873,
    0.15803465247154236,
    -0.002220466732978821,
    -0.0023632189258933067,
    0.03150435537099838,
    -0.0761573389172554,
    -0.3728805482387543,
    0.05395852029323578,
    -0.13205842673778534,
    0.019016679376363754,
    0.5200108885765076,
    0.2782735824584961,
    0.08217129856348038,
    0.06879977881908417,
    -0.3019191026687622,
    -0.21047928929328918,
    -0.2397751361131668,
    -0.14399221539497375,
    0.18687033653259277,
    -0.28487658500671387,
    0.11619545519351959,
    -0.18031732738018036,
    -0.059407636523246765,
    -0.11267021298408508,
    -0.02284402772784233,
    -0.45863431692123413,
    -0.06318340450525284,
    0.11655210703611374,
    -0.34693512320518494,
    -0.14945799112319946,
    -0.03837423026561737,
    0.13326743245124817,
    -0.04826241731643677,
    0.0984693095088005,
    -0.21571457386016846,
    -0.005599251948297024,
    -0.1000245064496994,
    0.03078708052635193,
    0.2257998287677765,
    0.23468151688575745,
    0.24614854156970978,
    0.057032980024814606,
    0.02590012177824974,
    0.06637579947710037,
    -0.09635362774133682,
    0.024511300027370453,
    0.054878443479537964,
    -0.019001495093107224,
    0.03533126041293144,
    -0.14802871644496918,
    0.05799974128603935,
    0.17114050686359406,
    -0.10243572294712067,
    0.1828196793794632,
    -0.06769229471683502,
    0.006715534254908562,
    -0.0621270090341568,
    -0.1239347904920578,
    0.4451303482055664,
    0.2674187421798706,
    0.21410731971263885,
    -0.13395659625530243,
    0.12177252024412155,
    0.13320210576057434,
    0.07968433201313019,
    0.07145310938358307,
    0.13488343358039856,
    -0.3376474976539612,
    -0.027925914153456688,
    -0.01877274364233017,
    -0.055770669132471085,
    0.07248318195343018,
    -0.1985192596912384,
    0.41558143496513367,
    -0.21470016241073608,
    0.00180653459392488,
    0.01230315025895834,
    -0.25784197449684143,
    0.16818946599960327,
    -0.13869279623031616,
    0.05139467865228653,
    0.010087383911013603,
    0.21821117401123047,
    -0.096829354763031,
    0.2613685727119446,
    -0.0634373277425766,
    -0.054010000079870224,
    -0.1985006034374237,
    0.03603208810091019,
    0.010746903717517853,
    0.40761250257492065,
    -0.04444914311170578,
    0.018095390871167183,
    -0.15173248946666718,
    0.15368790924549103,
    -0.17171593010425568,
    -0.06542578339576721,
    0.08967467397451401,
    0.023094654083251953,
    -0.11160144954919815,
    0.012936883606016636,
    0.03222038224339485,
    0.16139109432697296,
    -0.0698033794760704,
    0.0025200583040714264,
    -0.13830213248729706,
    -0.19908757507801056,
    -0.04465571790933609,
    -0.3257773518562317,
    -0.24122636020183563,
    0.2163548767566681,
    0.19657863676548004,
    0.24990913271903992,
    0.47722360491752625,
    -0.06870221346616745,
    0.4060593247413635,
    0.01270704809576273,
    0.12326160073280334,
    0.16875870525836945,
    0.10108403116464615,
    -0.06470170617103577,
    0.3649567663669586,
    -0.02642560750246048,
    0.18347720801830292,
    -0.04590265080332756,
    0.10154377669095993,
    -0.23013350367546082,
    0.11789771169424057,
    -0.14196179807186127,
    0.3111759424209595,
    -0.26989394426345825,
    0.10450435429811478,
    -0.08256083726882935,
    -0.09166324138641357,
    -0.43762388825416565,
    -0.03300127387046814,
    0.0586063377559185,
    0.023209918290376663,
    -0.04786481708288193,
    0.1297772228717804,
    0.031117932870984077,
    0.11111341416835785,
    -0.14740192890167236,
    -0.38679540157318115,
    0.02582015097141266,
    -0.05029628798365593,
    -0.2217729240655899,
    0.12298854440450668,
    -0.09051433205604553,
    0.03927312046289444,
    -0.09138064086437225,
    0.015250100754201412,
    0.19535471498966217,
    -0.09158895909786224,
    0.0305732823908329,
    0.22398902475833893,
    -0.059374526143074036,
    -0.2645154595375061,
    -0.35829195380210876,
    -0.06549274921417236,
    0.4043419659137726,
    -0.004617571830749512,
    -0.45933690667152405,
    -0.10569997876882553,
    0.06339605897665024,
    -0.06815588474273682,
    0.16382789611816406,
    0.2128928303718567,
    0.17163580656051636,
    -0.2520802319049835,
    -0.14742188155651093,
    0.03737369552254677,
    -0.6033905744552612,
    0.031192412599921227,
    -0.21649636328220367,
    0.1696641445159912,
    -0.14388948678970337,
    -0.15856055915355682,
    -0.016064852476119995,
    0.42502662539482117,
    0.2341223508119583,
    0.03241221234202385,
    0.11778842657804489,
    0.1338769644498825,
    -0.13620787858963013,
    0.010683199390769005,
    -0.22845351696014404,
    -0.3415237069129944,
    0.22950437664985657,
    -0.26249340176582336,
    -0.08501540869474411,
    -0.08903054147958755,
    0.037564851343631744,
    0.23414592444896698,
    0.34675508737564087,
    0.02467748150229454,
    -0.10153255611658096,
    -0.026179887354373932,
    -0.22871042788028717,
    -0.27654820680618286,
    0.05612671375274658,
    -0.08376747369766235,
    0.1049552634358406,
    -0.013511593453586102,
    0.09128926694393158,
    -0.0011982081923633814,
    0.05062413960695267,
    0.08689695596694946,
    0.23952849209308624,
    0.22834563255310059,
    -0.09084956347942352,
    0.18998661637306213,
    -0.3503563106060028,
    -0.19745531678199768,
    -0.03925514966249466,
    0.403876394033432,
    -0.30546900629997253,
    -0.0010978113859891891,
    0.058379046618938446,
    0.11505014449357986,
    0.07647787034511566,
    0.09666424989700317,
    -0.4285615384578705,
    0.22888298332691193,
    -0.09557950496673584,
    -0.014434341341257095,
    -0.11273092031478882,
    0.2225649058818817,
    0.1214723289012909,
    0.04134359955787659,
    -0.03408576548099518,
    0.3014944791793823,
    -0.06966336816549301,
    -0.015556447207927704,
    -0.1288650631904602,
    0.32450148463249207,
    0.24157102406024933,
    0.22649994492530823,
    0.09195432811975479,
    0.1324455887079239,
    -0.1840941458940506,
    0.037664055824279785,
    -0.0247283224016428,
    0.047795332968235016,
    -0.3711877465248108,
    0.11318389326334,
    0.10009285062551498,
    0.1690656542778015,
    0.0007055314490571618,
    -0.2665793001651764,
    -0.16162775456905365,
    -0.2143493890762329,
    -0.14732767641544342,
    0.03997492045164108,
    -0.08071522414684296,
    0.025499414652585983,
    -0.18366828560829163,
    -0.0026306267827749252,
    0.08807510882616043,
    0.05053887516260147,
    0.22644345462322235,
    -0.2249600887298584,
    0.0743359848856926,
    -0.06598254293203354,
    -0.15972834825515747,
    0.2019716501235962,
    0.007057833950966597,
    0.15507261455059052,
    -0.1137743890285492,
    -0.37573352456092834,
    -0.22254572808742523,
    0.2919546365737915,
    0.10227206349372864,
    -0.0021838638931512833,
    -0.06583461910486221,
    0.02697696164250374,
    -0.16031339764595032,
    0.0013091331347823143,
    -0.38167423009872437,
    0.048076413571834564,
    -0.3681448698043823,
    -0.0686948150396347,
    -0.12983432412147522,
    0.03042253479361534,
    -0.053054507821798325,
    -0.014269194565713406,
    0.027273066341876984,
    -0.08195088058710098,
    0.10262835770845413,
    -0.1975705325603485,
    -0.0011348258703947067,
    -0.008084496483206749,
    0.06330059468746185,
    -0.20593810081481934,
    -0.1521030068397522,
    -0.27547234296798706,
    0.13705690205097198,
    -0.22010597586631775,
    -0.23979435861110687,
    -0.027724653482437134,
    -0.060340628027915955,
    -0.09296640753746033,
    -0.12447866052389145,
    0.1831706464290619,
    0.14675945043563843,
    0.12313313037157059,
    0.007889466360211372,
    -0.14576762914657593,
    -0.16882596909999847,
    0.017858413979411125,
    0.2485218197107315,
    -0.11284790188074112,
    0.3009180426597595,
    -0.16467604041099548,
    -0.29391059279441833,
    0.12656885385513306,
    -0.15594497323036194,
    0.2736760973930359,
    -0.13790778815746307,
    -0.13983769714832306,
    0.26664501428604126,
    0.0009564720094203949,
    -0.3380361795425415,
    0.04647413641214371,
    -0.14481918513774872,
    0.04400748014450073,
    -0.021950390189886093,
    0.11120294034481049,
    0.034938834607601166,
    0.24248531460762024,
    -0.048552513122558594,
    -0.039130110293626785,
    -0.05664297565817833,
    0.293057382106781,
    0.23749183118343353,
    0.061890747398138046,
    0.2265649139881134,
    -0.21199457347393036,
    -0.19780850410461426,
    -0.10714740306138992,
    0.018297407776117325,
    -0.18729877471923828,
    -0.03931368514895439,
    0.07213057577610016,
    -0.45697465538978577,
    -0.019952062517404556,
    -0.2227146327495575,
    0.01789798028767109,
    -0.05090702697634697,
    -0.012803144752979279,
    0.12090910971164703,
    0.27642205357551575,
    0.28505101799964905,
    0.10090625286102295,
    0.14638441801071167,
    -0.2750594913959503,
    0.19013990461826324,
    -0.09395234286785126,
    -0.08940427750349045,
    0.29363691806793213,
    0.02967078983783722,
    0.05469975620508194,
    -0.27136000990867615,
    -0.09450405836105347,
    -0.13537903130054474,
    -0.02756226621568203,
    0.2398587465286255,
    -0.03860166668891907,
    -0.2633676826953888,
    0.1544223576784134,
    0.2102378010749817,
    -0.055723778903484344,
    0.18494635820388794,
    0.02430533431470394,
    -0.0014444207772612572,
    0.01646110974252224,
    -0.2884419858455658,
    0.06975653767585754,
    0.14280545711517334,
    0.21855656802654266,
    -0.054865360260009766,
    -0.2664768397808075,
    0.15404537320137024,
    0.07058555632829666,
    -0.2564086318016052,
    0.025546366348862648,
    -0.18019306659698486,
    0.025199588388204575,
    -0.06954245269298553,
    -0.17014487087726593,
    0.24414581060409546,
    -0.2120237797498703,
    0.08856579661369324,
    -0.07644421607255936,
    0.11976826190948486,
    0.176508828997612,
    0.16417363286018372,
    -0.04531588405370712,
    -0.23630917072296143,
    0.05578522011637688
  ]
}
```

Thank you so much in advance. :)

```
    {
        "$addFields": { 
            "target_embedding": target_embedding
        }
    }
    , {"$unwind" : { "path" : "$embedding", "includeArrayIndex": "embedding_index"}}
    , {"$unwind" : { "path" : "$target_embedding", "includeArrayIndex": "target_index" }}
    , {
        "$project": {
            "img_path": 1,
            "embedding": 1,
            "name" : 1,
            "target_embedding": 1,
            "compare": {
                "$cmp": ['$embedding_index', '$target_index']
            }
        }
    }
    , {"$match": {"compare": 0}}
    , {
      "$group": {
        "_id": "$img_path",
        "name" : { "$first": "$name" },
        "distance": {
            "$sum": {
                "$pow": [{
                    "$subtract": ['$embedding', '$target_embedding']
                }, 2]
            }
        }
      }
    }
    , { 
        "$project": {
            "name" : 1,
            "_id": 1
            #, "distance": 1
            , "distance": {"$sqrt": "$distance"}
        }
    }, { 
        "$project": {
            "name" : 1,
            "_id": 1
            , "distance": 1
            , "cond": { "$lte": [ "$distance", 4.15 ] }
        }
    }
    , {"$match": {"cond": True}}
    , { "$sort" : { "distance" : 1 } }
    ] )
```

Comment: Please provide sample documents and expected output in valid json documents. Currently, it is unclear what you are asking for as you just dump a bunch of code here. You should also illustrate how the calculation should be done.

Comment: Without knowing the specifics of your documents it's difficult to know for sure, but I suspect that the bulk of your pipeline (a vector dot product) can be replaced with a single `"$reduce"` operation.  And then isn't the _cosine similarity_ just dividing the dot product by the product of the two vector's magnitudes?

Comment: ... and since you appear to be sending `target_embedding` to the MongoDB server, I wonder if it would be more efficient to recall the stored `"embedding"` and calculate the cosine similarity within your app. ... or perhaps you are storing the cosine similarity?

Comment: hello @rickhg12hs I am storing only embedding in DB and I don't want to calculate distance on frontend (which is python BTW) because there will be more than 10M face embeddings.

Comment: 1. Don't provide sample documents as link as they could be broken in future. Instead, directly post the json content inside the question(This time we did it for you)
2. We still don't know the expected output

Comment: Thank you @ray :) aggregate should calculate distance and it should return only those documents whose distance is <= 0.68. will this help ??

Comment: So, as output you want something like `{"img_path": "1_11", "name": "11", "cos_sim": 0.5123}` for all documents where the cosine similarity is less than or equal to 0.68? ... or are you looking for just euclidean distance?

Comment: @rickhg12hs yes I am looking for or all documents where the cosine similarity is less than or equal to 0.68.

Comment: @Archish  Does my answer below provide a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the facial recognition domain so I don't know the significance of the 0.68 threshold, but it's easy to change the final `"$match"`.

The pipeline below:

1. Fetches a generated `"target_embedding"` (described below)
2. Calculates *cosine similarity* parameters using `"$reduce"`

   - dot product
   - sum of squares for document embedding
   - sum of squares for target embedding
3. Calculates *cosine similarity* as the dot product divided by the square root of the product of the two sums of squares
4. Thresholds using `"$match"`

Rather than loading a 512-length array into `mongoplayground.net`, I used its `mgodatagen` configuration option to create two collections: `"faces"` with a hundred documents of embeddings, and `"target"` with a single document/embedding used as `"target_embedding"`.  So, you'll need to change the initial pipeline stages to match your inputs.

```js
db.faces.aggregate([
  // go get the target embedding
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "target",
      "pipeline": [],
      "as": "target"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "target_embedding": {"$first": "$target.embedding"},
      "target": "$$REMOVE"
    }
  },
  // done getting target embedding
  //
  // calculate cosine similarity params
  {
    "$project": {
      "name": 1,
      "img_path": 1,
      "cos_sim_params": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": {"$range": [0, {"$size": "$embedding"}]},
          "initialValue": {
            "dot_product": 0,
            "doc_2_sum": 0,
            "target_2_sum": 0
          },
          "in": {
            "$let": {
              "vars": {
                "doc_elem": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$embedding", "$$this"]},
                "target_elem": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$target_embedding", "$$this"]}
              },
              "in": {
                "dot_product": {
                  "$add": [
                    "$$value.dot_product",
                    {"$multiply": ["$$doc_elem", "$$target_elem"]}
                  ]
                },
                "doc_2_sum": {
                  "$add": [
                    "$$value.doc_2_sum",
                    {"$pow": ["$$doc_elem", 2]}
                  ]
                },
                "target_2_sum": {
                  "$add": [
                    "$$value.target_2_sum",
                    {"$pow": ["$$target_elem", 2]}
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "name": 1,
      "img_path": 1,
      "cos_sim": {
        "$divide": [
          "$cos_sim_params.dot_product",
          {
            "$sqrt": {
              "$multiply": [
                "$cos_sim_params.doc_2_sum",
                "$cos_sim_params.target_2_sum"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "cos_sim": {"$lte": 0.68}
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ji6ACrUlO_5).

Comment: For which Embedding are you calculating Cosin Similarity?
Means How to insert target embedding variable?

Comment: @IdreesAhmed  In the aggregation pipeline shown, the embedding comes from a `"$lookup"` into another collection.  Of course those stages could be replaced by any other method that populates `"target_embedding"` appropriately.